# Como trabalhar com índice no thymeleaf?

Tags: html5, jsp

Através de um tutorial conseguir criar uma inclusão de produtos utilizando o seguinte código html

```
<c:forEach items="${tipos}" var="tipoPreco" varStatus="status">
            <div>
                <label>${tipoPreco}</label> 
                <input type="text" name="preco[${status.index}].valor">
                <input type="hidden" name="preco[${status.index}].tipo" value="${tipoPreco}">
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
```

Que fica da seguinte forma;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ela está vinculado a três entidades

De Produto;

```
@ElementCollection
private List<Preco> preco;
```

De Preco

```
private TipoPreco tipo;
```

E de TipoPreco que é uma enum

```
EBOOS,IMPRESSO,COMBO;
```

Estou tendo uma enorme dificuldade em realizar os códigos que fiz em JSP para fazer em thymeleaf.

Eu sei que existe algo em relação com o th:each

```
<option th:each="status : ${todosStatusTitulo}" th:value="${status}" th:text="${status.descricao}"></option>
```

eu fiz uma tentativas, mas foram em vão, preciso de sugestões de como poderia colocar o código do thymeleaf para ter o mesmo resultado a que eu fiz com JSP.

================================ATUALIZAÇÃO============================

Fiz a seguinte tentativa seguindo a sugestão proposta;

```
<div th:each="tipoPreco, status : ${tipos}">
    <label th:text="${tipoPreco}"></label> 
    <input type="text"  th:name="preco[${status.index}].valor"/> 
    <input type="hidden" th:name="preco[${status.index}].tipo" th:value="${tipoPreco}"/>
</div>
```

Gostaria de deixar claro como está o método que carrega o formulário;

```
@RequestMapping("form")
    public ModelAndView form(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("produtos/form");
        modelAndView.addObject("tipos", TipoPreco.values());

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

E diante da alteração feita gerou esse erro na pagina;

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Apr 10 06:48:06 BRT 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not parse as expression: "preco[${status.index}].valor" (produtos/form:30)
```

E essa foi a mensagem de erro no consoles;

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "preco[${status.index}].valor" (produtos/form:30)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:238) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:79) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:40) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.AbstractStandardSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.getTargetAttributeValue(AbstractStandardSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:65) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.getModifiedAttributeValues(AbstractSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:59) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:62) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
```

Ele está dizendo com essa mensagem de erro que ele não reconhece esse trecho do código como uma expressão regular do  thymeleaf.

```
<input type="text"  th:name="preco[${status.index}].valor"/>
```

Talvés a abordagem do thymeleaf para tratar index seja diferente do JSTL do JSP.

======================MAIS UMA TENTATIVA============================

Encontrei esse link

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#the-springstandard-dialect

e encontrei esse exemplo;

```
<table>
            <tbody>
              <tr th:each="row,rowStat : ${sb.rows}">
                <td th:text="${rowStat.count}">1</td>
                <td th:text="${row.variety.name}">Thymus Thymi</td>
                <td th:text="${row.seedsPerCell}">12</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

e tentei fazer assim;

```
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr th:each="tipoPreco,rowStat : ${tipos.rows}">
        <td th:text="${rowStat.count}">1</td>
        <td th:text="${row.preco.valor}">Thymus Thymi</td>
        <td th:text="${row.preco.tipo}">12</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

E deu esse erro;

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 6): Property or field 'rows' cannot be found on object of type 'br.com.casadocodigo.model.TipoPreco[]' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224) ~[spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94) ~[spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:46) ~[spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:374) ~[spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

============================SEGUNDA ATUALIZAÇÃO===============

Eu coloquei meu código dessa forma;

```
<tbody>
                <tr th:each="tipoPreco, row : ${tipos}">
                    <td>
                    <input th:text="${tipoPreco}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

E ao gerar os input´s eu tentei cadastrar esse registro e não tive sucesso em inserir registros nas base de dados no ebook, no impresso e combo, isso porque ele somente apresenta o nome dos valores que estão na classe enum, tenho que ter uma maneira de acessar a classe preco para poder inserir os valor

veja como está ficando no navegador

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando se usa o `th:each` o Thymeleaf oferece um mecanismo para você controlar a iteração, a **variável de status**. Ela é declarada após a **variável de iteração**.

A **variável de status** contém algumas informações tais como: `index`, `count`, `size`, `current` e outros que você pode olhar [aqui](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration).

No seu código fonte que está no GitHub, você está tentando iterar um Array de Enum. Logo os métodos ou atributos não estão disponíveis por isso acontece o erro:

```
property or field 'rows' cannot be found on object of type 'br.com.casadocodigo.model.TipoPreco[]' - maybe not public?
```

Troquei o seu código por este:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="tipoPreco, row : ${tipos}">
            <td th:text=" ${row.count}">

            </td><td th:text="${tipoPreco}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

E resultou na saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa linha `<tr th:each="tipoPreco, row : ${tipos}">` declarei primeiro a váriavel de iteração e depois a variável de status para manipulação de iteração.

Recomendo você ler a [documentação do Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#introducing-thymeleaf). Em PDF tem pouco mais de 85 páginas.

Comment: eu atualizei minha postagem.

Comment: Ai já entra a parte de cadastro e não trabalhar com th:each. Vai ser preciso analisar com mais calma todo seu código para ver o problema. E qual foi o erro que ocorreu quando você tentou cadastrar?

Comment: ele somente  cadastrou titulo, descrição e paginas na base de dados.

Comment: O Spring MVC não está conseguindo fazer o bind, da forma que você deseja, do form para sua entidade de negócio.

Comment: é isso mesmo que está acontecendo.

Comment: Recomendo você fechar essa pergunta, marcando alguma resposta como aceita, pois ela se trata do problema com índice,  e abrir uma pergunta sobre Bind de formulários com Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Faltou apenas concatenar o texto estático do `th:name` com o valor dinâmico vindo do status. O código correto seria esse:

```html
 <div th:each="tipoPreco, status : ${tipos}">
    <label th:text="${tipoPreco}"></label>
    <input type="text" th:name="'preco['+${status.index}+'].valor'">
    <input type="hidden" th:name="'preco['+${status.index}+'].tipo'" th:value="${tipoPreco}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div th:each="tipoPreco, status : ${tipos}">
    <label th:text="${tipoPreco}"></label>
    <input type="text" th:name="'preco['${status.index}'].valor'">
    <input type="hidden" th:name="'preco['${status.index}'].tipo'" th:value="${tipoPreco}">
</div>
```

Comment: acabei de atualizar a postagem, poderia dá uma olhada, por favor!

Comment: fiz uma segunda atualização.

Comment: Tente isso `modelAndView.addObject("tipos", new ArrayList(TipoPreco.values()));`

Comment: somente basta modificar o controller e deixa do jeito que você sugeriu a cima na sua ultima postagem de sugestão?

Comment: `@RequestMapping("form")
    public ModelAndView form(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("produtos/form");
        modelAndView.addObject("tipos", new ArrayList(TipoPreco.values()));

        return modelAndView;
    }`

Comment: Ele não permite tal modificação no controller porque na tabela produtos já existe uma lista com o atributo preco como lista.

Comment: O meu projeto não está em fase de conclusão, na verdade eu criei no dia que fiz essa postagem. quer que eu poste meu projeto no GitHUb para você dá uma olhada?

Comment: Sim. Assim vai ficar mais fácil te ajudar

Comment: meu projeto se encontra aqui >>>   https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/casadocodigo/tree/master/casadocodigo

Comment: se tiver dificuldade para importar o projeto, me informe, por favor

Comment: algum resultado?